# Negative indices in Swift arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, indices

Is it possible and easy to have the first index in an array to start on a negative number instead of 0?

If so, how would I define the following so these start on -1 instead of 0? And how do I access the value?

```
var myIntArray:[Int] = [4, 2, 1]
var myDoubleArray:[Double] = [28, 28, 14]
var myCGFloatArray:[CGFloat] = [0.14, 0.14, 0.1]
```

Comment: Why do you need it to start at -1 instead of 0? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have preferences that users saved that references an index of 1 as the default. The elements in the array make sense to progress left to right. I'm adding a 3rd element at the beginning. I'd like to reference that as -1, so that their saved values in their prefs don't throw things off.

Comment: If you really want negative indexes, I would recommend using a dictionary. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

Comment: Array indices start at zero. You can define a custom subscripting method if (really) necessary.

Comment: An array of preferences really sounds like the sort of thing you should use a dictionary or other non-order-dependent object for. Better to work with the tools rather than try to fundamentally redefine their behavior.

Comment: I use a plist dictionary, and one of those just those things that are stored happens to be an array index with type Number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom subscript for that:

```
extension Array {
    private var customIndexOffset: Int { return -1 }

    subscript(customIndex index: Int) -> Element {
        get {
            return self[index - customIndexOffset]
        }
        set {
            self[index - customIndexOffset] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Now `myIntArray[customIndex: -1]` **==** `myIntArray[0]`

### - More generic, wider coverage:

```
extension MutableCollection where Index == Int {
    private var customIndexOffset: Int { -2 }

    subscript(customIndex index: Int) -> Element {
        get { self[index - customIndexOffset] }
        set { self[index - customIndexOffset] = newValue }
    }
}


extension Collection where Index == Int {
    private var customIndexOffset: Int { -2 }

    subscript(customIndex index: Int) -> Element { self[index - customIndexOffset] }
}
```

Comment: It could be customized to support more negative indices

Comment: Exactly, with any offset you need. I have edited the code to make it more customizable and less hard coded with a single source of truth.